# Problem with matching setup in Moq

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I've been using Moq for the past week or so and haven't had any issues until today. I'm having a problem with getting `VerifyAll()` to properly match the setup of my mock.

I'm currently writing unit tests for my application's API. Here's how the application is structured:

`API <==> Service <==> DAO <==> Database`

With this in mind, I'm mocking the service object and then constructing an API object using the mocked service. I've written a number of unit tests already without problem up until now.

I have two instance variables like this:

```
private Api _api;
private Mock<IHibernateService> mockService;
```

I initialize these in a setup method:

```
[SetUp]
public void DoSetupTasks()
{
    mockService = new Mock<IHibernateService>();
    _api = new Api(mockService.Object);
}
```

Here is the unit test that is failing:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestSearchOnAllProperties()
    {
        mockService
            .Setup(service => service.LoadAll(It.IsAny<Type>()))
            .Returns(new DomainBase[0]);

        var dmbs = _api.SearchOnAllProperties("search term", typeof(DomainBase));

        mockService.VerifyAll();
    }
```

The API's `SearchOnAllProperties()` method will subsequently make a call to the service's `LoadAll()` method (with some additional logic of course), so I want to verify that it's being called properly. To clarify, here's how `LoadAll()` is being called in `SearchOnAllProperties()`:

```
public IEnumerable<DomainBase> SearchOnAllProperties(string searchTerm, Type type)
{
    foreach (DomainBase dmb in _hibernateService.LoadAll(type))
    {
        // additional logic
    }
}
```

However, when I run the unit test, I get a `MockVerificationException` stating that the given setup was not matched. I cannot figure out why as it should be calling the service's `LoadAll()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible cause is that at some point before this particular test method is called, `mockService` is being assigned to a new instance of `Mock<IHibernateService>`.  If that is the case, then this test method would be calling `Setup` on the wrong instance, which would then produce this exception.

A quick way to test this would be to use local `mockService` and `api` variables and see if the test still fails:

```
[Test]
public void TestSearchOnAllProperties()
{
    var localMockService = new Mock<IHibernateService>();
    var localApi = new Api(localMockService.Object);

    localMockService
        .Setup(service => service.LoadAll(It.IsAny<Type>()))
        .Returns(new DomainBase[0]);

    var dmbs = localApi.SearchOnAllProperties("search term", typeof(DomainBase));

    localMockService.VerifyAll();
}
```

HTH

Comment: I should have clarified that I have tried initializing mockService and _api locally within the test case and the problem still persisted.

Comment: @Tyler, I copied your code and it passed, so it should not be a problem with Moq.  Is your `Api` class doing anything that might assign its internal `IHibernateService` variable to a new instance?

Comment: It seems like it's a problem when the method call being matched is part of another expression, like: `foreach (Type t in _hibernateService.GetAllDomainTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType != null && t.BaseType.Name == "DomainBase" && !t.IsAbstract)`. I've set the mock to strict, but there's no exception. It appears no methods are being called at all.